# Redirecting to same file name but different extension in IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I recently inherited a website running coldfusion. Sometime in the last year, all the `.htm` files were renamed to `.cfm`. Problem is that some external sites were already linking to the `.htm` versions, and now those links are broken.

I'm trying to find a way to redirect the user to the `.cfm` file if a `.htm` file is requested but not found (and of course, it's CF counterpart is present). I'm new to IIS and just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS7 you can create a rewrite rule that will redirect the requests from .htm to .cfm  Alternatively you could set the error template to a 404.cfm that will check if the equivalent file in .cfm exists and then redirect to the appropriate file or publish the standard 404.

Comment: The 404 CF file sounds like the better way to go. Thanks!